# Cyclically reduced words and Cayley graphs

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $S$ be a symmetric generating set for $G$. For simplicity, assume $S$ does not contain involutions. Cyclically reduced words can be thought of as minimal length representatives of their conjugacy class in $Free(S)$. I am interested in certain properties of cyclically reduced words over $S$ and the values they correspond to in $G$.

1) Can every $g \in G$ be represented by a cyclically reduced word over $S$? Every element of $G$ can certainly be expressed as a reduced word over $S$ (simply because the Cayley graph $Cay(G,S)$ is connected, as $S$ is a symmetric generating set). But is this true for (the more restricted) cyclically reduced words too?

UPDATE: The answer is YES, since the group is finite.

2) The total number of cyclically reduced words of length $k$ over $S$ with $|S|=2m$ is
$$(2m-1)^k + m + (m-1)(-1)^k$$
as shown in [Reduced Words of Length $l$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825830/reduced-words-of-length-l?rq=1) and the references mentioned. But suppose I want to know how many cyclically reduced words evaluate to a specific element $g \in G$, then is there some closed form expression for this?

For instance, if we are interested in the number of reduced words of length $k$ that map to a particular element of $G$, then we can write this out using the non-backtracking operator on the adjacency matrix of $Cay(G,S)$. This is because the sequence of directed edges on a non-backtracking walk on the Cayley graph can be interpreted as a reduced word over $S$. Using known properties of non-backtracking walks as discussed in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226925/what-does-this-connection-between-chebyshev-ramanujan-ihara-and-riemann-mean
this problem of reduced words can be dealt in a fully combinatorial fashion.

However, cyclically reduced words involve more delicate properties of the group and generating set (or labelled edges in the Cayley graph). But I am curious if we can construct some $|G| \times |G|$ matrix 
$$B_k$$
such that for every $g_1,g_2 \in G$,
$$(B_k)_{g_1,g_2} = \#\{\text{cyclically reduced words of length k that evaluate to } g_2g_1^{-1}\}$$
on the lines of the similar analysis of reduced walks using non-backtracking operators.

Crossposted from MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272178/cayley-graphs-and-cyclically-reduced-words